# No overload for method takes 1 arguments

Tags: oracle, model-view-controller, methods, arguments, overloading

I have one store procedure in my oracle database same this:

```
    create or Replace PROCEDURE  ussd_100(INSHENASEHG      IN      VARCHAR2,
                                   outSHENASEHP     out  varchar2,
                                   outamt           out  number)
IS
Begin

      Select  a_SHENASEHP,nvl(a_amtkol,0)-nvl(a_cred,0)   InTo  outSHENASEHP,outamt  From A_ghabz

      Where    A_SHENASEHG=INSHENASEHG AND A_YEAR=95 AND A_ghabz=1;
  End ;  
/
Commit;
Show Errors;
```

when I call this procedure in my asp.net mvc action same under:

```
   public ActionResult SearchEshtrak(string A_SHENASEHG)
       {

           return db.USSD_100(A_SHENASEHG).ToString();

         }
```

I have under message error:

No overload for method 'USSD_100' takes 1 arguments

please help me.thanks

Comment: the procedure has 1 in and 2 out parameters.  You are passing in 1 in parameter but the way oracle works with out parameters you need to pass  in variables for the out parameters to go into.

Comment: thanks for you. I  change my action same this and remove the error:     public ActionResult SearchEshtrak(string A_SHENASEHG,ObjectParameter oUTSHENASEHP1,ObjectParameter oUTAMT1)    but  nothing act in this action...!!???

Comment: how I call this (oracle) procedure from my action mvc? can you show a example? thanks

Comment: Can't test this at the moment don't have access to appropriate environment but what I was referring to was your call 'return db.USSD_100(A_SHENASEHG).ToString();' would need to change to  somthing like 'db.USSD_100(A_SHENASEHG, outparam1, outparam2);' Then you would need a separate statement to return whatever you wanted. eg a concatenation of the two out parameters.

Comment: public ActionResult SearchEshtrak(string A_SHENASEHG, ObjectParameter oUTSHENASEHP, ObjectParameter oUTAMT)
          {

              return View("SearchEshtrak", db.USSD_100(A_SHENASEHG,oUTSHENASEHP, oUTAMT).ToString());
        }   ////very thanks.that is ok...